# Is it possible to model list / dict like elements in HTML forms?

Tags: python, html, flask

I wrote a python script that is creating switch configs out of .yaml files. 
And I'm not sure how to create a web form that fits my needs.

I'm completely open on how to accomplish this. I just need a way to post values to my python script.

My HTML Form looks like this:

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="port"></input>
<input type="text" name="port.mode"></input>
</form>
```

The posted data gets into Flask like this: 
[('port', 'Port1'), ('port.mode', 'Access')]

I'd like to have the data like this: 
{ "ports": { "port1": {"mode": "Access"}}}

++Update
I'm already using Jinja to create the template. 
Sample Jinja Template:

```
{%- for name,options in ports.items() %}
interface {{ name }}
{%- if options.mode == 'access' %}
switchport mode access
{% else %}
switchport mode trunk
{% endif %}
```

My Problem is between the HTML form and the template engine. I'm not sure how to model my HTML form to fit my needs.

2 ways I can think of accomplish this. 
 1. Alter the HTTP Post request in Javascript before submitting
 2. Writing a sever-side python code to bring the HTTP Posted data into the correct form for my jinja Template.

But I' completely open to the method I use. I'm not limited to flask, jinja and python.

Comment: Use jinja or some templating engine, they support loops natively, which is what you are trying to do.
Also if you are using flask they commonly go toghether take a look http://jinja.pocoo.org/

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "posting values from a web form to a Python script"?  I think you would use JavaScript for something like this, assuming the Python script resides on the web server.  Or are you trying to generate HTML dynamically based on the .yaml configuration file?

Comment: He is already using flask, he needs to pass the form to the template renderer, it is pretty common practice but not that straightforward

Comment: Hi, 
thanks for your comments.
I edited my answer to clarify it. The problem ist not creating the template. My problem is to getting the HTTP posted data into the form i want.

Answer (score -1):

is this a solution?

```
In [1]: x = [('port', 'Port1'), ('port.mode', 'Access')]
In [2]: {x[0][0]: {x[0][1]: {x[1][0]: x[1][1]}}}
Out[2]: {'port': {'Port1': {'port.mode': 'Access'}}}
```

Comment: Hi Paul, 

yes it's kind of what I'm trying to accomplish. But I got nearly 100 different attributes. And I'm trying to avoid mapping every single attribute by hand.